# How to test network connectivity on specific UDP port between 2 linux hosts

Tags: linux, networking, port, syslog

I am looking for a method to test network connectivity on specific port between 2 linux hosts.

Let's say for an example: I am sending syslog events from server A to server B on port 514. However, server B never receive events from Server A. I can confirm server A is sending it and port 514 on server B is opened. For now, I am suspecting that firewall between these servers are blocking 514 connections.

Is there any tool or method that can help to verify if firewall is opened for port 514 in this situation?

Comment: thanks you for your information...it seems tcpdump is the only tool that can help here...

Comment: Simple networking troubleshooting: run tcpdump on serverA and serverB at the same time, do your application stuff on serverA, check the packet appears on A tcpdump (meaning the packet is leaving host) and check if packet appears at the same time on server B (meaning the packet arrived on host). If the packet arrived on B but not on B application then there is a firewall/misconfiguration on B. If it never arrived on B, it means some network configuration dropped it during its travail from A to B. The `socat` tool can be useful for tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you can do.

First, check if the services you believe are running and listening on certain ports are indeed listening, to do that, use netstat:

```
netstat -plunt
```

More than that, you can use a packet analyzer like Wireshark or the Linux built-in tool which is called tcpdump.

To analyze all traffic on let's say network interface card named eth0, run:

```
tcpdump -i eth0
```

To analyze all traffic on nic eth0, protocol udp and port 514:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -n udp 'port 514'
```

If you suspect the firewall in one of the machines then you can list all the active rules on the machine by issuing the next command:

```
sudo iptables -S
```

More information about iptables command you can run to help you troubleshooting your problem can be found [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-list-and-delete-iptables-firewall-rules).

Another troubleshooting step I would take would be to telnet from the syslog sender machine to the syslog receiving machine in port 514:

```
telnet hostB:514
```

If your session is opened then it means that hostA can reach hostB in the given port.

Comment: telnet won't work for UDP.  netcat could be useful,  nc -u

Comment: thanks you for your information...it seems tcpdump is the only tool that can help here

Comment: Thanks to @JohnMahowald, `nc -u` was what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `traceroute` to find out how far packets of a specific protocol gets. Here is an example of what the command could look like:

```
traceroute -n -T -p 514 2001:db8::1
```

The meaning of the arguments are as follows:

- `-n` disables reverse DNS which often will make the command run much faster.
- `-T` perform the trace using TCP SYN packets.
- `-p 514` send the packets to port 514
- `2001:db8::1` the IP address of the destination. A hostname could be used as well.

Compare the output for a few different port numbers to find out if one is consistently being treated different from the others.

Notice that different versions of `traceroute` exist. The above was tested using the one from the `traceroute` package on Ubuntu 16.04. That version is also known as `traceroute.db`.

Comment: syslog uses UDP by default, so `-T` will test something completely different (UDP may be blocked and not TCP or the opposite), hence this does not seem to fit the question.